# Question about units of formal power series

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I have some questions when watching [the following clip](https://youtu.be/fc0p5ESPp5A?t=134). The gist of the part of the lecture is that the professor suggests an example where Cartier does not correspond to Weil. My question that I ask would not be deeply related to the concept of divisor. My essential question is just how the derived result computes. (Rather, it is related to the abstract-algebra) Anyway, he gives an example  $X=\operatorname{Spec} R$ (where $R=k[[t^2,t^3]]$) and according to the lecture,

$~~~~~(Cartier)= \frac{Units~ of ~ k}{Units~of~R}\overset{^{(★)}}{=}\frac{at^n(1+a_1t+a_2t^2+...)}{a(1+a_2t^2+...)} \simeq  \mathbb{Z} \times k$ (where $a$ is a unit of $R$)[!]............ $(1)$

The first equality of $(1)$ is just the definition of Cartier divisor. On the third part of $(1)$, is also understandable to some extent on the lecturer's remark. However, I do not understand why equality (★) holds. First, I know the following **Fact** is a essential tool understand to (★).

> **Fact**. Let $R$ be a ring with identity. and suppose $f= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a_i x^i \in R[[x]]$. Then $f$ is a unit in $R[[x]]$
> iff its constant term $a_0$ is a unit in $R$

On the denominator part of (★),  combining with **Fact** and the notation of $k[[t^2,t^3]]$, which has no term of $a_1$, I can guess the form of unit of $k[[t^2,t^3]]$. Thus, in my thought, the units of $k[[t^2,t^3]]$ would be $a+a_2t^2+...$(where $a$ is a unit of $k$), but it is different to his result. Also, he said that $a \in R$ [!] , but is it right that $a\in k$ by the **Fact**?

On the numerator part of (★), , according to the lecturer, the following

$~~~~~~~~~~$(units of $k$)$~=~$(units of $k[[t]][t^{-2}]$)$~=~$ $at^n(1+a_1t+a_2t^2+....)$ .....................$(2)$

holds. However, I do not know why each equality holds. Above all, I do not see the idea why first equality of $(2)$ holds. And to see the second equality on $(2)$ , it might be applied the **Fact**, but I cannot obtain why the calculation carries the following result.